# preg_match() + 0-1x and digit

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I trying to make regexp for telephone numbers. Resp. for this input:

```
+420123456 -> valid
123456 -> valid
```

Respective I want regexp where can be one or zero **+** folowed 1 or n **digits**

```
function isTelephoneNumber($telephone) {
    preg_match("~^[+]{0,1}[0-9]+$~", $telephone,$match);
    return (count($match)>0) ? true:false;
}
```

also tried

```
"~^\+{0,1}[0-9]+$~"
"~^[+]?[0-9]+$~"
"~^\+?[0-9]+$~"
```

But something is wrong with the + character.

Comment: your regex works fine.

Comment: In fact, all of your attempts look fine to me (although I'd prefer `"(^\+?\d+$)"` personally)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Why a capturing group?

Comment: @AvinashRaj It's not a capturing group. I use parentheses as delimiters for two reasons: 1. No need to escape anything "just because it's a delimiter". Ever. 2. It reminds me that `[0]` in the result is the whole match.

Comment: It's not your regex, perhaps another problem? https://eval.in/174639

Comment: its strange, the regex is ok, but I use ajax for the form, $telephone = $_POST["telephone"], first strange thig is that when I echo $telephone i get 420123456 insted of +420123456 what I put in the form ... :/

Comment: haha it replaxe + by x :/

Answer (score 1):

Your `+` is not escaped. This one should do the job :

```
preg_match("/^\+?\d+$/", $telephone,$match);
```

`\+?` => zero or one **+**

`\d+` => one or more digits